# why is there extra space between url-tagged events?

Tags: css, fullcalendar, spacing

I have a fullcalander spacing bug that I can't get past.

Here is what my calendar looks like when my data doesn't have links in it

[image]

```
$ticketData[] = array(
                'id' => $ticket->getId(),
                'title' => $title,
                'start' => $ticket->getArrival()->format('Y-m-d'),
                'end' => $ticket->getDeparture()->format('Y-m-d'), 
            );
```

Now when I add a URL:

[image]

Has this weird bug happened to anyone else? I'm really lost as to what's going on. The only line I added was the url:

```
$ticketData[] = array(
                'id' => $ticket->getId(),
                'title' => $title,
                'start' => $ticket->getArrival()->format('Y-m-d'),
                'end' => $ticket->getDeparture()->format('Y-m-d'), 
                    'url' => $url
            );
```

Here is how I'm calling the calender:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    editable: false,
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },
    events: data_url,
    loading: function(bool) {
        if (bool) 
            $('#loading').show();
        else
            $('#loading').hide();
});
```

Comment: Do you have a link to your website?  I am not familiar with this plugin, but this looks like a css problem.

Comment: this is inside a user area so i can't give a link. i've looked @ the css, and the events are all absolutely positioned so I can't adjust anything like padding or margin.

Comment: Can you give an example of what might be stored in `$url`?

Comment: It might have to do with CSS ? a { } applyes to all link , even  with no href, a:link { } does apply only to link with href, is that a tip ?.CSS would be usefull to see too.

Comment: Have you tried setting the display property of the offending links to 'block'?  Also, have you checked the line-height?

Answer (score 0):

This is almost definitely a CSS issue. My guess is that you've got padding or margins hitting those links.